# Modifying UIButton Programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, interface-builder

In my app, I have a UIButton that is pressed for both starting and stopping an event. I am currently trying to change the title of the UIButton and it's background image programmatically using the following IBAction:

```
    @IBAction func StartandStop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if StartandStop.titleLabel?.text  == "Start Flight" {
        StartandStop.setTitle("Stop Flight", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        StartandStop.setImage(UIImage(named: "End"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    else if StartandStop.titleLabel?.text  == "Stop Flight" {
        StartandStop.setTitle("Start Flight", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        StartandStop.setImage(UIImage(named: "Start"), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

My program starts like this:

[image]

However, after I press the button the first time it becomes this:

[image]

When I continue to press the button it remains in the second state. Why is my button doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `func setBackgroundImage(_:, forState:)` instead of `func setImage(_:, forState:)`, in addition, I would use `func titleForState(:)` instead of `titleLabel?.text`.

```
@IBAction func StartandStop(sender: AnyObject) {
    let title = StartandStop.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)
    if title? == "Start Flight" {
        StartandStop.setTitle("Stop Flight", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        StartandStop.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "End"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    else if title? == "Stop Flight" {
        StartandStop.setTitle("Start Flight", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        StartandStop.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Start"), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll take a look at the titleForState function too. Have a great evening!